# How to replace node-fetch with a runtime agnostic/worker fetch dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a dependency that's using node-fetch. The dependency itself checks for the existence of the library or falls back to global fetch. In dev I'd like to use node-fetch since I'm in Node however when I build for deploy to a Cloudflare worker I'd like it to be stripped from the build process entirely.